# How to create a event observer which trigger after a customer placed an order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

**Magento ver. 1.9.3.2**

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\local\Maddy\Checkout\etc\config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Maddy_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
         <models>
            <maddy>
                <class>Maddy_Checkout_Model</class>                
            </maddy>
        <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <maddy_sendsms>
                        <class>Maddy_Checkout_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>orderSms</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </maddy_sendsms>
                </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\code\local\Maddy\Checkout\Model\Observer.php

```
  <?php
class Maddy_Checkout_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderSms(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $incrementId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $custName    = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getCustomerFirstname();
        $orderPrice  = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getGrandTotal();
        $orderId     = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $order       = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()
        $mobile      = trim($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('telephone'));
        echo "I am here";
        die;
        /* I will write sms api here  */
        echo "Mobile" . $mobile;
        echo "<script>alert('Just to check')</script>";

    }
}
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\magento1\app\etc\modules\Maddy_Checkout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Maddy_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

When  order is placed no alert is shown.

UPDATE:
if I use event based trigger I am not able to do add to cart. If I delete this module g then add cart is working.There is no log for this.

**UPDATE:1.1**

After creating some observers i am came to know that never echo any thing directly in observers , even dump in log to see the output. It will not break the functionality than.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code

app/etc/Modules/Maddy_Checkout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Maddy_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Maddy/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Maddy_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
         <models>
            <maddy>
                <class>Maddy_Checkout_Model</class>                
            </maddy>
         </models>
        <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <maddy_sendsms>
                        <class>Maddy_Checkout_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>orderSms</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </maddy_sendsms>
                </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Maddy/Checkout/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Maddy_Checkout_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderSms(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        echo $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
        echo $custName    = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
        echo $orderPrice  = $order->getGrandTotal();
        echo $orderId     = $order->getId();        
        echo $mobile      = trim($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('telephone'));
        echo "I am here";
        die;              

    }
}
```

Comment: app/code/etc/Modules/Maddy_Checkout.xml  is this path correct ?

Comment: ah no. `app/etc/Modules/Maddy_Checkout.xml`

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: i used app/etc/Modules/Maddy_Checkout.xml . still no result .

Comment: placed all code same as above  ?

Comment: Yes , even I deleted my folder and placed yours.

Comment: create new files and folder as per answer. your one  is totally wrong

Comment: I updated my question as you suggested.

Comment: 1 min checking..

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: i think there is an error in ocnfig near  <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <maddy_sendsms>

Comment: updated `app/code/local/Maddy/Checkout/etc/config.xml` and   `Observer.php`

Comment: it should work now

Comment: `</models>` closing tag was missing

Comment: i have removed all other code from `Observer.php` to check it quickly

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan update your result here

Comment: @Manish i followed as you said . But  still no die

Comment: i have checked in my setup and is working fine

Comment: Let me try this on live website.

Comment: if i use event based trigger i am not able to do add to cart. If i delete the coding then add cart is working.There is no log for this

Answer (score 0):

just replace with .

Instead of

```
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

replace with

```
<sales_order_place_after>
```

and your `Observer.php` class name should be `Maddy_Checkout_Model_Observer`

Comment: I chnged as you suggested but nothing shown

Comment: am i using wrong path

Comment: put `die;` in observer method and check because i doubted that alert will not work at there

Comment: i used die() still order is placed successfully.

Comment: this is a after event means after order successfuly placed this event will fire

Comment: means when order status changed from pending to something else from admin side?

Comment: no when order is placed

Comment: sir no die is executed after order is palced. Is there any mistake in my code

Comment: am i using wrong paths  app/code/local/Maddy/Checkout/Model/Observer.php

Comment: no this path is right

Comment: do you have any  external link on this

Comment: your class name is wrong in that file it should be `Maddy_Checkout_Model_Observer`

Comment: still die() not run . This is the url www.sitename.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/success/ after placing order

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan added answer.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala module name and class name mismatch

Comment: @MineshPatel ahh  I didn't notice that +1 from my end

Comment: hmm created full module :)